# How do I convert img's src to an image and save to a folder?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently working on a page that allows the user to crop an image from modal screen and pass the cropped image to an `img` element using `canvas` as its data. The `img`'s `src` attribute has this random bunch of characters that starts with `data:image/png:base64 ...`. What I want to do is that when I finally hit <kbd>SAVE</kbd>/<kbd>SUBMIT</kbd> in my registration form, this image will then be converted to a new image file and saved to a specified folder.

Here is the code I used to crop the image and pass to the `img` element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $uploadCrop = $('#cb').croppie({
        enableExif: true,
        viewport: {
            width: 250,
            height: 250,
            /*type: 'circle'*/
        },
        boundary: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        }
    });

    $('#file1').on('change', function() { 
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
                url: e.target.result
            }).then(function(){
                console.log('jQuery bind complete');
            });
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    });

    //THIS OPENS A MODAL SCREEN THAT ALLOWS THE CROPPING OF SELECTED IMAGE
    $('#cropBtn').on('click', function(e) {
        $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
            type: 'canvas',
            size: 'viewport'
        }).then(function (canvas) {
            // This is the code that passes the result to another image file which will then be used to produce a new image file to save in to the directory for a particular user account profile photo.
            $('.profilePic').attr('src', canvas);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use `php`s `gd2` library:

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```